# PHP : How to interpret google url

Tags: php, url, google-search

I would like a tips about how to force this script to interpret the google url as if i'd done the research on google

```
<?php 

$ch = curl_init(); 
$timeout = 5;
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.google.com/?q=cr#hl=fr&q=help+me+please&psj=1&oq=variable+get+google+recherche&fp=1/'); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout); 
$file_contents = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch); 
$lines = array(); 
$lines = explode("\n", $file_contents); 

foreach($lines as $line_num => $line) { 
echo "Line # {$line_num} : ".htmlspecialchars($line)."<br />\n"; 
} 

?>
```

This is what I've come with, but when I try this on my server I only get google.com source code and not the source code from the google page after the research.

Can anyone help me ? thanks :D

Comment: possible duplicate of [I want to cURL google search result in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9392818/i-want-to-curl-google-search-result-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't the best way you could be doing this.

The JSON/Atom custom search API will do what you want. http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/v1/overview.html

For Yahoo, the BOSS API: http://developer.yahoo.com/search/boss/

And for Bing: http://www.bing.com/toolbox/bingdeveloper/

Additionally, the reason your CURL isn't giving you the results you need is because the search query is behind a hash in the URL. That means Google is pulling the results in via ajax. You will have to find a way to directly pass the query string to the google results page.

You can attempt to simulate this by turning javascript off in your browser, performing a search, and copying the resulting URL.

For the lazy, this is: http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=test+search

Comment: This is just the first step of my project, i'll have to do this on yahoo and bing later, not sure that google's API can do that

Comment: I don't think what you're trying to do is supported by Google. Bing and Yahoo also have search APIs. I will update my answer with links to those APIs as well.

Comment: Thanks for th update, way better now, im trying to take it to the next step, find how to isolate the nuber of results after a search on google, long night coming =p

Answer (score 0):

you can use Google Mobile view

http://www.google.com/gwt/x?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fsearch%3Fq%3Dkeyword&btnGo=Go&source=wax&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8

or You can use Google API to get google search results in json format

For web search
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?q=keyword&v=1.0&start=8&rsz=8

For image search
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?q=keyword&v=1.0&start=8&rsz=8

For video search
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/video?q=keyword&v=1.0&start=8&rsz=8